# Using gridview within a masterpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, visual-studio-2005, master-pages

I am creating a new page in VS2005 (VB) and it has a gridview, my problem is when I try to insert the grid into the ContentPlaceHolder (in design mode) it ends up somewhere else on the page all together.  I am using a masterpage, but not sure what I am doing wrong.

ASPX code

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/secure/Master1.Master" CodeBehind="Master1.Master.vb" Inherits="Main.LiveCalendar" %>

<asp:Content ID="ContentPlaceHolder" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<h1>Live Calendar</h1>

        <%--<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblMessage" Text=""></asp:Label>--%>
        <asp:gridview id="GridView1" runat="server" allowsorting="True" autogeneratecolumns="False"
                datasourceid="SqlDataSource1" style="z-index: 100; left: 0px; position: absolute;
                top: 0px" Height="101px" Width="224px"><Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="P_AE_ID" SortExpression="P_AE_ID" HeaderText="P_AE_ID"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="P_Name" SortExpression="P_Name" HeaderText="P_Name"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="P_Start" SortExpression="P_Start" HeaderText="P_Win_Start"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="P_End" SortExpression="P_End" HeaderText="P_Win_End"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="P_Status" SortExpression="P_Status" HeaderText="P_Status"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="True" DataField="CountOfPED_ID" SortExpression="CountOfPED_ID" HeaderText="CountOfPED_ID"></asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
        </asp:gridview>
        <p>
            &nbsp;<asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnection %>"
                selectcommand="web_Public" selectcommandtype="StoredProcedure"></asp:sqldatasource>

        </p>


</asp:Content>
```

Comment: The above code seems fine, are you sure you are pointing to the correct contentplaceholder on the masterpage? If you can please also add your masterpage code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not exactly understand what you mean by
"it ends up somewhere else on the page all together" 
But if yourproblem is about with the location of the grid change its z-index and position properties

Comment: It is not showing up in the contentplaceholder, it shows up out side of the place holder, specifically in the left corner above the header and logo.

Comment: try it with removing or changing the z-index pls